# Problemas para ver el certificado SSL en mi página web

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

¿Cómo puedo obtener símbolo con el candado verde o la indicación "conexión segura" en la dirección URL de mi navegador?

1.- Ya tengo una certificación SSL proporcionada por mi hosting (Ionos).

2.- Tanto mi dirección de Wordpress (URL) como la dirección del sitio (URL) comienzan con "https: /" en lugar de "http: /"

3.- También he redireccionado a la nueva URL con https:/ todo el tráfico recibido en http:/ mediante la redirección 301 en .htaccess

4.- Además he eliminado la caché de Wordpress usando el complemento "WP Super Cache"

¿Qué más necesito para ver el símbolo con el candado verde?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No nos das suficiente información para responderte, pero presumo que se trata de contenido mixto. Instala el plugin Better Search and replace, y reemplaza todas las cadenas http:// por https:// en todas las tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás en el camino correcto:

1.- Necesitas una certificación SSL. Tu hosting te la proporcionará, generalmente está incluido en el paquete de hosting.

2.- Ya sea Wordpress o cualquier otro CMS, debes dirigir a los visitantes al sitio correcto, tal vez al principio tenías una URL que comenzaba por http:/, por lo que si desea pasar al nuevo sitio seguro, debe dirigirse correctamente a la nueva https:/.

3.- Si tu sitio web ya tiene algún tiempo y quieres redirigir a https:/ a cualquier visitante que vaya a http:/ puedes agregar a tu fichero .thaccess el código correcto para hacer este redireccionamiento (301):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R, L]
</IfModule>}
```

4.- Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que no solo la dirección de su sitio debe modificarse de http:/ a https:/ también deben moverse TODOS los enlaces internos contenidos en el sitio. Tiene sentido: tu página web sólo es segura si los enlaces internos también lo son. Para resolverlo rápidamente uedes usar un código más genérico:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {SERVER_PORT}! ^ 443 $
RewriteRule (. *) Https: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI} [R = 301, L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .php $ - [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
RewriteRule. /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

5.- Lo más probable es que esto no sea suficiente. Ten en cuenta que, por ejemplo, todas tus imágenes que hasta ahora estaban dirigidas a http:/...img ahora deberían estar dirigidas a https:/. Por lo tanto, debes buscar (ctrl + f) http:/ en el código fuente de la página (en cualquier navegador haz clic con el botón derecho del ratón en la página que intentas proteger -> "ver código fuente"). Luego edita el archivo html relacionado con esta página y simplemente sustituye cada http:/ por el correspondiente https:/

6.- Solo cuando hayas asegurado todos los enlaces, tu sitio será seguro. Se valiente y sigue adelante, el éxito está al final.

Fuentes:

https://www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/como-activar-ssl-y-https-en-wordpress/
https://www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/cache-wordpress#Como-borrar-la-cache-en-WordPress